# Why is the bash completion setting in root's .bashrc is commented out in Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and I found that in root's .bashrc file, the bash completion setting is commented out by default:

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
# if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#     . /etc/bash_completion
# fi
```

When I uncomment it, the completion works again. Why it was commented by default? Is this related to any security considerations?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 20.04, too. Bash completion is enabled by default, even for root, by `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` in package "bash-completion". Maybe something disabled it on your system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is explained right there in the code you show. Just read the comment (emphasis mine):

> enable programmable completion features (**you don't need to enable
> this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
> sources /etc/bash.bashrc**).

Completion is enabled by default on Ubuntu systems because of the file `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`:

```
$ cat /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
# Check for interactive bash and that we haven't already been sourced.
if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION-}" -a -n "${PS1-}" -a -z "${BASH_COMPLETION_VERSINFO-}" ]; then

    # Check for recent enough version of bash.
    if [ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -gt 4 ] || \
       [ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -eq 4 -a ${BASH_VERSINFO[1]} -ge 1 ]; then
        [ -r "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/bash_completion" ] && \
            . "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/bash_completion"
        if shopt -q progcomp && [ -r /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
            # Source completion code.
            . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
        fi
    fi

fi
```

This file, in turn, is sourced by `/etc/profile`, a file that is read when login shells are launched:

```
 $ grep -A6 profile\.d /etc/profile
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

This means there is no need to re-enable it in root's `~/.bashrc` file, it is already enabled through the files above. Indeed, the code you show is pointless since the default contents of `/etc/bash_completion` on Ubuntu are just:

```
$ cat /etc/bash_completion
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

Which is exactly the command already present in `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`.